# filetransfer path

Tags: cordova, file-transfer

Is it just possible to upload a file over the URI parameter?

```
function upload(path) 
{
          var options = new FileUploadOptions();
          options.fileKey="file";
          options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
          var params = new Object();
          params.value1 = "test1";
          params.value2 = "param1";

          options.params = params;
          options.chunkedMode = false;

          var ft = new FileTransfer();
          ft.upload(path, "http://yourdomain.com/REST/upload.php", win, fail, options);
 }
```

If I am uploading a picture to the with the URI:

```
content://media/external/images/media/2749
```

its working fine, but with the fullpath:

```
/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/133028890065.jpg
```

file not found. Do I have to add something in the path?

If I want to upload video or audio, how to get the URI of those files?

```
function video() {  
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {
limit: 1});
```

}

because in these functions I just have access to the path with object.fullpath where I couldn't find anything how to get the URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileTransfer.upload() method should accept:

```
 1. content://media/external/images/media/1234
 2. file:///sdcard/DCIM/Camera/133028890065.jpg
 3. /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/133028890065.jpg
```

What does your "adb logcat" look like?

Comment: This is strange, I was running my app in the simulator and then it was working with the fullpath (3) and now also on the device?! before I got a "file not found" - thx for the help, filetransfer is pretty nice